# Laravel relationships table show

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

i am new to laravel and working on relationships
i have a phonebook which it has a client in it so when i insert the data i add some client id to it how can i get the client name in phonebook view when i am showing the list of phonebooks i want to get client object and show the name with it like this $client->title 
and here is my code maybe i cant define it in words :)
this is my PhonebookController

```php
public function index()
{

    $phonebooks = Phonebook::all();
    $client = Phonebook::find(?dont know if its right place for it?)->client;
    return view('admin.phonebooks.index',compact('phonebooks',$phonebooks),compact('client',$client));
}
```

and here is Phonebook model

```php
class Phonebook extends Model{
protected $fillable = ['title','description','client_id','calldate','rememberdate'];
public function client() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Client','id');
}    }
```

here is my phonebook db migration

```php
Schema::create('phonebooks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('title');
        $table->longText('description');
        $table->integer('client_id');
        $table->dateTime('calldate');
        $table->dateTime('rememberdate');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and  the client db migration

```php
 Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('title');
        $table->longText('description');
        $table->integer('fax');
        $table->text('adrress1');
        $table->integer('telephone1');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and finally here is the view

```php
 @foreach($phonebooks as $phonebook)
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{$phonebook->id}}</th>
        <th scope="row">{{$phonebook->title}}</th>
        <td><a href="/admin/phonebooks/{{$phonebook->id}}">{{$phonebook->description}}</a></td>
        <td>{{$phonebook->calldate}}</td>
        <td>{{$phonebook->created_at->toFormattedDateString()}}</td>

        <td>{{$client->title}}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                <a href="{{ URL::to('admin/phonebooks/' . $phonebook->id . '/edit') }}">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">edit</button>
                </a>&nbsp;
                <form action="{{url('admin/phonebooks', [$phonebook->id])}}" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="delete"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

If client hasMany Phonebook entry (and phonebook belongsTo client) then you need a client_id column on the phonebooks table

Then in the client model

```
public function phonebooks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(App\Phonebook::class);
}
```

In the phonebook model

```
public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(App\Client::class);
}
```

In the controller

```
    $phonebooks = Phonebook::with('client')->get();
    return view('admin.phonebooks.index',compact('phonebooks'));
}
```

Your $phonebook models will all have a `->client` relation, so in the view

```
<td>{{$phonebook->client->title}}</td>
```

Comment: aa yeah that code worked that unfortaulnty i was wrong i see now that i need something else a client belongs to many phonebooks and a phonebook hasone client can you just help me with that ?